# Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios

I am developing swift project using some objective-c files via "bridge-header-file".Its working fine for first time. I just close the xcode and reopen my project and i run it. But not working...showing "Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code"
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check the Path in

`Target -> Built Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header`

Correcting the path works for me in Xcode 12.